# Jquery code working fine until I included strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, strict

A piece of Jquery Code was working just fine until "superiors" told me I must include strict mode on all my Javascript code. Everything is working fine on my main.js file except this piece of code. I can't reccon the error but my console error triggers every time i activate the script, it is a Boostrap 4 toggler button, it does open a menu, but the menu opens from up to bottom and really laggy. The button is supossed to collapse from right to left.

```
$(function(){
    // mobile menu slide from the left
    $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function() {
        $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
        $navMenuCont.animate({'width':'toggle'}, 280);
    });
})
```

Console error goes as follow:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $navMenuCont is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:61)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
```

Comment: You failed to declare that variable `$navMenuCont`. It needs to be declared with `var` or `let` or `const`.

Comment: That's basically the point of "strict" mode. (Well there are other things, but I mean why did you add "use strict" if you didn't expect to find things like this?)

Comment: Already solved, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MDN reference:

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"
>   (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript).
>   Assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead
>   throw an error in strict mode.

You need to declare your `$navMenuCont` variable.
For example:

```
var $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode